# Code for creating dependent options in Volusion

Tags: html, dependencies, volusion

I working on setting up a new site and Volusion doesn't appear to have any tools available to create dependent options. I will have products on the store that will have multiple option combinations (see example below)

Option 1: Color (Red, Blue,Green)

Based on the selection of option 1, I need the correct option 2 to appear.

Option 2: Personalization
If red is selected---Line 1: 5 characters  Line 2: 10 characters
If blue is selected---Line 1: 5 characters
If green is selected-- Line 1: 8 characters   Line 2: 20 characters

While I would LOVE for the personaization options to appear and link to the option 1, I would also be okay to just use the "Option Side Note" in Volution which can automatically populate a note of text. Does anyone know an HTML code I can use for the Color option so that the text notes would automatically change to let the customer know the lines and characters to include?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for Volusion SmartMatch functionality, at least in part.

http://support.volusion.com/article/smart-match

Comment: Thanks for providing feedback with my Volusion option set issue. The problem with smartmatch is that it will only work for options that are both drop down boxes. In this situation, the second option needs to be text so that it captures the personalization details.